# How to set a custom timeout value for Android WebView page load

Tags: android, webview, timeout, connection-timeout

I would like to set a custom value for HTTP connection of my WebView. How can I customize it?

I read a lot of posts about a parallel timer to detect the timeout, but it is not what I'm lookin for, I need to define a new custom value for HTTP load timeout.
Is there any chance to do it? Maybe overriding the default HTTP client?